# Can you transfer weights partially in blender?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to transfer weights from one mesh to another, but I don't want to transform all of the weights, just one in a specific area. Is there any way to do this, or will I manually have to replicate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the vertex group (the weights) to the selected object from the active, if they have the same geometry, then you can remove the unwanted weights easily, by selecting them and click on remove in the Vertex Groups tab.[image]